# Grease Pencil Object Transparency - Not Respected between Objects

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil

I'm having an issue with Grease Pencil in Blender 3.0.

I have a grease pencil object with transparency, that intersects with another grease pencil object. (A creature standing in water). The transparency is shown on all other objects in the scene, so you can see through the water, but on the other grease pencil object (the creature) it just cuts off the image where they intersect. I've included a screenshot to illustrate the issue.

[image]

The issue is also present if I use a standard 3D object as the water, as shown below.

[image]

Has anyone come across this before, and has any advice on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a mesh issue on the ground plane extruding past the Grease Pencil object.

Tested transparency in a new document with just some simple objects and it worked fine, went back to this and removed the modifiers and the clipping stopped.